# Разделить латиницу и киррилицу

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть входная строка типа: `"hello мир пока world"`
Нужно две строки: `"hello world"`, `"мир пока"`.
Как такое на питоне сделать проще?

Comment: Что делать с цифрами и прочими запятыми?

Comment: @Эникейщик Удалить лучше.

Comment: А слова целиком либо на кириллице, либо на латинице?

Comment: @splash58 Смешанные тоже удалить. В каждом списке не должно быть букв из другой раскладки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь регулярными выражениями:

```
import re
```

---

```
In [114]: s = "hello мир, пока world! 123 смешаnnie sloва"

In [115]: latin_str = ' '.join(re.findall(r"\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b", s))

In [116]: cyrillic_str = ' '.join(re.findall(r"\b([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)\b", s))

In [117]: latin_str
Out[117]: 'hello world'

In [118]: cyrillic_str
Out[118]: 'мир пока'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
def parse_words(string_):
    lat = "a-zA-Z"
    cyr = "а-яА-ЯёЁ"
    all_words = re.findall(rf"\b([{lat}{cyr}]+)\b", string_)
    latin_words = re.findall(rf"\b([{lat}]+)\b", string_)
    cyrillic_words = re.findall(rf"\b([{cyr}]+)\b", string_)
    mixed_words = set(all_words) - (set(latin_words) | set(cyrillic_words))
    # return " ".join(latin_words), " ".join(cyrillic_words), " ".join(mixed_words)
    return tuple(map(" ".join, (latin_words, cyrillic_words, mixed_words)))


latin_words, cyrillic_words, mixed_words = parse_words(s)
```

---

результат:

```
In [145]: latin_words
Out[145]: 'hello world'

In [146]: cyrillic_words
Out[146]: 'мир пока'

In [147]: mixed_words
Out[147]: 'смешаnnie sloва'
```

Comment: `r"\b[a-zA-Z]+\b"` - мне кажется, абсолютно тоже самое

Comment: @splash58, согласен, знаки вопроса можно убрать...

Comment: и группу - зачем она вам, если \b - нулевой длины

Comment: @splash58, привык использовать группы в `re.findall()` )

Comment: @MaxU А если смешанные в 3 строку?

Comment: @A.King, можно пример?

Comment: @MaxU В smesh_str поместить 'смешаnnie sloва'.

Comment: @A.King, смотрите UPDATE...

Comment: @MaxU Мм..хитро!

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения

```
import re
line = "hello мир пока world"
russian_words = " ".join(re.findall(r"[а-я ]+", line, re.I))
english_words = " ".join(re.findall(r"[a-z ]+", line, re.I))
```

Так же чтобы удалить лишние пробелы можно использовать конструкцию:

```
russian_words = " ".join(russian_words.split()).strip()
```

Comment: Как всегда, `ё` посеял...